# Chromecast send message to sender from receiver

Tags: javascript, html, chromecast

I'm trying to send a an array to my sender from my receiver but when I try it it will turn it into a string.

I have the code:

```
messageBus = window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus(namespace, cast.receiver.CastMessageBus.MessageType.JSON);
```

and

```
messageBus.send(senderId, ["test", "test2"]);
```

In my receiver and in my sender:

```
session.addMessageListener(namespace, function (ns, message) {
    console.log(message);
    console.log(typeof(message));
});
```

The output in my console is:

```
["test","test2"]
string
```

How can I send an array to my sender?

Answer (score 0):

By default, you cannot send an array; you can either send a string or a JSON packet. If you were to want to send an array, you'd have to define your own serializer and deserializer for the messageBus so as to keep your message as an array. To avoid doing this, then, you could sending a JSON packet:

```
messageBus.send(senderId, {"msg": ["test", "test2"]});
```

Then, on the sender, you can use the message.msg part of the object in ways similar to an array (or even convert it to an array).